# FileMaker Pro 12 Auto-populating Tables

Tags: filemaker, auto-populate

I'm new to Filemaker and need some advice on auto-populating tables.

Part 1:

I have `TableA` which includes many records with client information. I want a separate `TableB` which is identical to `TableA` except that it is "de-identified"; that is, it does not contain two of the fields, first name and last name.

I would like the two tables to interact such that if I add a new record to `TableA`, that same record (sans first and last name) appear automatically in `TableB`.

Part 2:

In addition to the above functionality, I would also like said functionality to be dependent on a specific field type from `TableA`. For example, I enter a new record, which has a "status" field set to "active," into `tableA`. I then want that record to be auto-popualted into `TableB`; however, if I add another record with a "status" of "inactive," I want that that record auto-populated into a `TableC` but not into `TableB`.

Answer (score 2):

FileMaker can perform this with script triggers so long as every layout where `TableA` will be edited has a layout script trigger of `OnRecordCommit` connected to it. When the record is committed (which can happen in a number of ways), the attached script will run, which you can use to create the appropriate record in the appropriate table.

The script could create the record in a number of ways. If the primary keys for both records are the same, you could use lookups. You could export the record in `TableA` and then import it into the correct table. You could pass the field information as a parameter to the script. The best choice really depends on your needs.

Having said that, I would question the wisdom of this approach. It brings up a few questions that would seem to complicate matters. For example, what happens when the status changes? When a record in `TableA` is deleted? When fields in `TableA` are modified? Each of these contingencies (and others) will require thought and more complicated scripts.

So I would ask what problem you're really trying to solve. My best guess is that you are trying to keep the name information private from certain users. User accounts and privileges with dedicated layouts for each privilege can solve this without the need for duplicate tables. FileMaker privilege sets can be quite granular.

For example, you can specify that users with PrivilegeA can create records and view names, but PrivilegeB users can only view records if the status is "active" and the name fields are not available to them, while PrivilegeC users can view records if the status is "inactive" and the name fields are also not available to them.

Comment: I agree with Chuck: setting up three separate tables that contain basically the same data seems like a nightmare to maintain. For most problems, privilege sets and different layouts seems like a better way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely use filters and permissions on the "status field" to achieve this and not two mirroring tables. Unless the inactive information is drastically different, you would be complicated your solution and creating more possible pitfalls.